# Dynamic dns update

Tags: dns, mdns, jmdns, reverse-dns, dyndns

We have created 3 DNS servers in our local machine with primary server(10.42.0.80) , secondary(10.42.0.70) and cache(10.42.0.83). We are able to ping it perfectly but while doing Dynamic Dns update we are getting connection refused in header.
We have done following entries:-

```
1) /etc/resolv.conf:-
nameserver 10.42.0.83 (it is cache server)

2) /etc/bind/named.conf.options file:-

forwarders  
       { 

    10.42.0.83;(it is cache server)

    127.0.0.1;(it is localhost)
         };
```

output in console:-

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: REFUSED, id: 39911
;; flags: qr ra ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 0 ad: 0 
;; ZONE:
;;  thegeekstuff.net., type = SOA, class = IN

;; PREREQUISITES:

;; UPDATE RECORDS:

;; ADDITIONAL RECORDS:

;; Message size: 34 bytes
```

can anyone suggest why we are getting this connection refused error while doing Dynamic DNS update.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting a connection refused but a DNS REFUSED message which indicates that the requested action is not allowed.

Have you enabled updates with the allow-update statement in the config? If not, you will need to do so. Look at configuring allow-update-policy as well if needed. You'll likely want to set up a TSIG key to only allow updates from an authorized user.

One more thing, you may wish to use allow-update-forwarding if you expect your secondary server to received the DDNS request and forward it to the primary.

See http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#allow-update for more details. That link takes you the allow-update section but the other statements are there as well.